# jquery - event handler works if pasted into Console but not when included through .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application using jquery 3.2.1

One of the pages contains 2 `<form>` elements which have the same class name, `.products-ctp__search-form`. The HTML for this is rendered on page load:

```
<form class="products-ctp__search-form">
     <input name="n1" type="text">
</form>

<form class="products-ctp__search-form">
     <input name="n2" type="text">
</form>
```

I want to target the `<input>` elements in each form and use an event handler to deal with the user entering input into either of them. So I've written this inside a `foo.js` file and then linked it at the bottom of the page:

```
<!-- Form markup above is here -->

<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

The `foo.js` file contains:

```
$(function() {
    $('.products-ctp__search-form input[type="text"]').bind("keyup change input",
    function (e) {
        console.log('debug');
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

When I enter text into either input it doesn't log anything to the console.

But if I paste the script above into my console, it will, e.g.

```
debug
VM726:4 r.Event {originalEvent: InputEvent, type: "input", target: input#n1.form-control.form-control.input-border-secondary, currentTarget: input#n1.form-control.form-control.input-border-secondary, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, …}
```

Strangely if I get rid of 1 of the inputs (e.g. removing the form containing `n2` and keeping `n1`) it works fine. Other pages in the application have just 1 input and the equivalent code - when included from a linked `.js` file - works fine.

So I've read [jquery works in console, but not in linked js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354286/jquery-works-in-console-but-not-in-linked-js-file) but this seems to suggest waiting for something to load. In this case the markup is rendered on page load (not via ajax, etc) and the jquery code is inside `document.ready`.

There is another post [jQuery works in console but not in .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212574/jquery-works-in-console-but-not-in-js-file) which I read but again this seems to suggest having to wait for something to load. If this is the case then *what* am I supposed to wait for and how to I bind this?

The linked posts make sense when you're waiting for something like an image to load. But how does this work if it's just the markup of the page? Or is that not actually the problem?

jquery is included in the `<head>` of the document whereas the `foo.js` file is inside `<body>`. So I don't believe it's an issue of `foo.js` being included before jquery, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and found that `console.log(e)` is causing issue (not sure why it is throwing error in console). Comment this part and don't use `bind`, use 'on' as bind is deprecated in jquery.

```js
$(function() {
   $(document).on("keyup change input", '.products-ctp__search-form input[type="text"]', function (e) {
        console.log('debug');
        //console.log(e);
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="products-ctp__search-form">
     <input name="n1" type="text">
</form>

<form class="products-ctp__search-form">
     <input name="n2" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work. What do you mean by "getting load dynamically"? The inputs are rendered on page load, they are within the HTML of the document. That isn't dynamic?

Comment: as you said it works when it is under n1 and not working from n2. how are you filling forms data?

Comment: I'm filling the forms by clicking into the input and typing into them - no autofill

Comment: don't use `bind` as it is deprecated, use `.on`

Comment: Right, well you've already given `.on` in the answer and it still doesn't work

Comment: i have updated my post, tried to reproduce your issue and found that `console.log(e);` throwing error and commenting it gives me desired result. Try my post and let me know if that works for you

Comment: It works in a fiddle and above but not in my application. Maybe something else is conflicting on the page? Unfortunately I can't post the full page content as it's a proprietary application with private content.

Comment: please check console error if there is something you can figure out and fix the issue